# How to use a host-based USB printer from WinCE

Tags: printing, usb, driver, windows-ce, printers

I'm testing an HP LaserJet printer with WinCE7, it's a host-based (not PCL) printer.

When it's plugged into the USB port of WinCE, the USBPRN.dll is loaded but PCL.dll is not loaded which is as expected.

I included wordpad in WinCE and tried to print from wordpad, but there is a error message box saying no printer babah. Printer setting dialog box is not displayed.

Then I use CreateFile/WriteFile/CloseHandle APIs and try to send some ASCII string to the LPT1 port.

The return handles are valid but **nothing** happened on the printer. According to the debug log, I see something wrong inside WriteFile although the return value is valid.

Then I'm stuck.

I have several other options to try:

1. Use OpenPrinter/StartDocPrinter/WritePrinter API set. But I'm not
   sure if they are different from CreateFile/WriteFile/CloseHandle.
2. Check to see if there's any open sourced driver for the printer in
   Linux world, then I can see what's the data & format I should send
   to the printer. But I don't know Linux at all. I'm not sure what
   part is different from Windows to Linux or what part is same to
   different OS.
3. Anyone can point out any information about how to implement a
   host-based printer driver? Just introduction about the architecture
   is also welcome. For example, is there anything related to the
   device context (DC) or bitmap or anything else.

I'd like to see any comment on which direction I should go.

Thanks,
Fei

Comment: option 2 seems to be very difficult for a windows developer. I downloaded the linux driver, the souce code package is more than 30M! and I don't know where to begin with.